# Call an object function from a text variable

Tags: javascript

```
app = {
    echo: function(txt) {
       alert(txt)
    },
    start: function(func) {
        this.func('hello'); 
    }
}

app.start('echo');
```

I need to call whatever function passed as func. How to do that? the example doesn't work for me.

Comment: Do you have to use strings? Why can't you just pass the function to call?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `this[func]` instead of `this.func`

```
   app={
          echo:function(txt){
          alert(txt)
          },
         start:function(func){
            this[func]('hello');
          } 
        }

      app.start('echo');
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess in it's simplest form you could do:

```
var app =
{
  echo: function(txt)
  {
    alert(txt);
  },

  start: function(func)
  {
    this[func]("hello");
  }
};
```

But you could get a little smarter with the arguments:

```
var app =
{
  echo: function(txt)
  {
    alert(txt);
  },

  start: function(func)
  {
    var method = this[func];
    var args = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++)
      args.push(arguments[i]);

    method.apply(this, args);
  }
};
```

That way you can call it as `app.start("echo", "hello");`

Comment: You can also use arrays slice instead of manually looping through arguments array, even tho not directly `var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);`

Answer (score 2):

Try that way:

```
start: function(func) {
    this[func]('hello'); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
start:function(func){
this[func]('hello');
}
```